# MapBox - Unable to create new empty dataset with api and php cUrl. I get message not found error

Tags: php, mapbox, php-curl

I have the following php cUrl script.  I am trying to create a new empty dataset on mapbox via their api.  The below receives a form submission of dh_dataset_name and dh_dataset_description then then encodes it to json and then submits to the api with cUrl, however, I get an error of `{"message":"Not Found"}`.  How can I submit to mapbox's api to create an empty dataset using cUrl php?  Any pointers appreciated.

```
        $ski_datasets_create = $this->request->getPost();
       
        $data[] = array(
            'name' => $this->request->getPost('dh_dataset_name'),
            'description' => $this->request->getPost('dh_dataset_description')
        );
       
        $payload = json_encode($data);
       
        $url = "https://api.mapbox.com/datasets/v1/[snip:username]?access_token=[snip]";
       
        $request = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_URL,            $url);
        curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,  "POST");
        curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $payload ); 
        curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Content-Type: application/json'));

        $repsonse = curl_exec($request);
        
        echo '<pre>';
        curl_errno($request);
        curl_error($request);   
        print_r($repsonse);    
        echo '</pre>';
        die();
```

I only get below error message which is not helpful:
`{"message":"Not Found"}`

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a very cool feature on POSTMAN.  If you are able to get it working in POSTMAN, there is an export code feature.  The below is a modified version of the php cURL export but it works:

```
        $ski_datasets_create = $this->request->getPost();
       
        $data = array(
            'name' => $this->request->getPost('dh_dataset_name'),
            'description' => $this->request->getPost('dh_dataset_description')
        );
       
        $payload = json_encode($data);

        $url =  $this->data['dh_mapbox_api_url'].$this->data['dh_mapbox_username'].'?access_token='.$this->data['dh_mapbox_admin_token']; 
        
        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $payload,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                'Content-Type: application/json'
            ),
        ));
        
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
```